# chart.js v4 truncate scale/labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

similar questions has been asked here in the past but eventually for older versions of Chart.js. The accepted answers of the questions didn't work.
I have a chart like this:
[image]

The code of this chart is this:

```js
    new Chart(
      document.getElementById("chart-01"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: { 
          labels: ["Test loooooong 1", "Test loooooong 2", "Test loooooong 3"],
          datasets: [{ data: [574.48, 140.93, 64.37]}]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              ticks: {
                callback: function(value) {
                  return '$ ' + value;
                }
              }
            },
            // x  : {
            //   ticks : { 
            //     callback : function(value, index, ticks) { return value.split(0,8)+'...';}
            //   }
            // }
          },
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-vCUbejtS+HcWYtDHRF2T5B0BKwVG/CLeuew5uT2AiX4SJ2Wff52+kfgONvtdATqkqQMC9Ye5K+Td0OTaz+P7cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="chart-01" width="500" height="600"></canvas>
```

I am trying to truncate the names on the x-axis after 8 chars and add a '...', So if I am using that commented code block:

```
x  : {
  ticks : { 
    callback : function(value, index, ticks) { return value.split(0,8)+'...';}
  }
}
```

I get the error message:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: value.split is not a function**

Also if I use only the value, without split, I get numbers back but not the label names.

This are links to solutions that did not work for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537545/3408158
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418430/3408158

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get/change the value of the label you have to use the function `getLabelForValue`.
*([here an example from the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html))*

And `split` is the incorrect function you would need to use `substring`.
*([link to the mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring))*

**Here all the fixes entered into your example code:**

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: { 
        labels: ["Test looooong 1", "Test looooong 2", "Test looooong 3"],
        datasets: [{ data: [574.48, 140.93, 64.37]}]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: { callback: value => `$ ${value }` }
            },
            x: {
               ticks: { 
                   callback: function(value){
                       let newLabel = this.getLabelForValue(value)
                           .substring(0,8) + '...';
                       return newLabel;
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
   <canvas id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

> **Information:** The mentioned solutions don't worked because, as far as I can tell, they are base on he chartjs Verion 2.0+, and since then the chartjs library change substantially.